# jQuery, an issue with this method

Tags: jquery

```
var contactForm =
    {
        form: $('.contact'),
        button: $('button'),
        config: {
            type: 'slideDown',
        },

        init: function (config)
        {
            $.extend(this.config, config);

            contactForm.button.on('click', function() 
            {
                if(contactForm.form.is(':hidden'))
                    this.showForm();
                else
                    this.closeForm();
            });
        },

        showForm: function ()
        {
            contactForm.form[contactForm.config.type](2000);
        },

        closeForm: function ()
        {
            contactForm.form.slideUp(2000);
        },
    };

    contactForm.init();
```

In init() function, I tried to call showForm() and closeForm() methods by using 'this'. However, 'this' is appointed to the click element. (the button)

How can I prevent this?

I always want 'this' to contain struct/class object. If I want a button object be appointed, I want it to be appointed into $(this), not this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
init: function (config)
{
    var self = this;
    $.extend(this.config, config);

    self.button.on('click', function() 
    {
        if(contactForm.form.is(':hidden'))
            self.showForm();
        else
            self.closeForm();
    });
},
```

Comment: There is no other solution other than caching 'this'? Like an inbuilt javascript/jquery feature?

Comment: No there isn't, I don't like it that much either but it's the way the language works...

Comment: @AnılÜnal You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind, but then `this` will not the button.

Comment: Well, if it's the way language works, I'll obey to it then. I wish there was an alternative object which refers to class though, would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is declare a var pointing to `this` outside of your handler function and use that. That's the only way, using closures.

```
init: function (config){
    var me = this;

    $.extend(this.config, config);
    contactForm.button.on('click', function(){
        if(contactForm.form.is(':hidden'))
           me.showForm();
        else
           me.closeForm();
    });
}
```

That's the only way, it's the way the language works.